# Why SQLServer2012Dialect initialization takes so long in a spring boot project?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate

I wrote a spring boot REST API that connects to a SQL Server 2017 Express database with number of tables - 38. When I start the spring boot project the log stops at a line that indicates that SQLSServer2012Dialect is initializing. It takes several minutes for the log to resume its work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqA4L.png)

> 2022-07-25 10:49:40.983  INFO 15532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
> 2022-07-25 10:54:14.810  INFO 15532 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not the dialect that takes so much time to initialize, but the schema validation/update or metadata retrieval.

Try using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` and see if that works out for you. If that doesn't help, I guess the latency between your app and database must be very high. In that case, there is not much you can do except for trying to buy a better connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, When I disable schema validation it sometime it fast and sometime it slow it's not stable like I use with MySQL database

Comment: Like I wrote before, this can have several reasons that could be on the network level (latency) or database level (too many connections, locking) or anywhere else really. You will have to profile your application startup to understand to figure out what it is exactly that takes long and where you have to look deeper.